# Laravel 5.4 Chat client side error related to pusher

Tags: laravel, chat

I am following the instruction of the github package for chat in laravel which is on the link: https://github.com/jplhomer/laravel-realtime-chat-demo.

I follow each and every instruction but in the end i get a javascript error:

> ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined

Can anybody help?

Comment: did you include pusher js lib?

Comment: @Hanlin Wang I did it this way. 
import Pusher from "pusher-js". but i got further errors